# Twilio TCDevice connect timeout

Tags: ios, twilio

I am wondering if there is a way to change the timeout on the outgoing call from `[TCDevice -connect:delegate]` in the Twilio iOS client. I have tried playing with different key/value pairs in the `connect` options NSDictionary but nothing seems to have an effect.

Comment: By timeout, do you mean how long Twilio Client will try to connect to Twilio before giving up?

Comment: If you try to a call a client that is currently offline, the Twilio Client will disconnect within 10 seconds. I would like to extend this timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

For using `timeout` from the mobile client, you can embed the `timeout` parameter in the `connect:delegate:` method of `TCDevice`:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/TCDevice#connectDelegate

For example:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"timeout": @"10"};
self.connection = [self.device connect:params delegate:self];
```

It sounds like you were trying this, but maybe missed to get this `timeout` argument in your TwiML app and add it into the response which is eventually sent to HUrl.